# How to use string as equation in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

So,I have a string, let's say - 1+2-1+9-3 and I need to use it as equation and need to change text to result of this equation. How can i make it? I already did adding numbers to string, so i only need to get result of equation.

Comment: you use `loadstring`,  and prepend a return to the string. `print(loadstring("return -1 + 2 - 1 + 9 - 3")())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse the string as a line of code, use `loadstring()`. This is basically the equivalent to JavaScript's `eval()`. Just keep in mind you have to allow loadstring to be used on your experience by clicking on ServerScriptService and checking the `LoadStringEnabled` box under **Behaviour**.

## Example

### Code

```
local parsecode = "1+2-1+9-3"
local parseres = loadstring("return "..parsecode)()
print(parseres)
```

### Code Result

```
8 - Server - Script:3
```